# Eliminate Blank Rows When Creating .CSV File

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a macro to create .CSV file that contains the first to last row of data entered. When I run the Macro, blank rows are showing in the .CSV file. What code do I need to eliminate the blanks rows from being written to the file? Listed below is the VBA code and a snapshot of the data in the .CSV file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
' DeleteHeadings
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.DeleteShift:=xlUp


'Find thelast Row with data in a Column
DimLastRow As Long
DimFirstRow As Integer

With ActiveSheet
LastRow =.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With


FirstRow= 1


'SelectRows to Save
Range(Cells(FirstRow,"A"), Cells(LastRow, "BH")).Select

' SaveActive Workbook As CSV
Application.DisplayAlerts= False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAsFilename:="Z:\RDS\Towers_Watson_Trans_File1", FileFormat:=xlCSV,CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.CloseSaveChanges:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts= True
```

Data from .CSV file

```
444444444,,HILDA,,ZOLDAN,19490611,F,{92B32AFF-7A9C-4FB0-BC98-51CBA0F642CC},20150801,1800.00,M,20150801,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,915 
444444444,,MARY,,SHANAHAN,19501111,M,{92B32AFF-7A9C-4FB0-BC98-51CBA0F642CC},20151101,1080.00,M,20151101,,,,,, , , , , ,,,,,,,, 
444444444,,MARY,,SZCZESNIAK,19450923,F,{92B32AFF-7A9C-4FB0-BC98-51CBA0F642CC},20150801,1800.00,M,20150801,,,, , , , , , , ,,,, 
444444444,,DORIS,,HAMMONDS,19461214,F,{92B32AFF-7A9C-4FB0-BC98-51CBA0F642CC},20150801,1800.00,M,20150801,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,37 
666666666,,ROSA,,GANA,19530613,F,{92B32AFF-7A9C-4FB0-BC98-51CBA0F642CC},20180601,1080.00,M,20180601,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,71SACK 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Isn't the sheet saved as a .csv not a selection? You may have to do something like`range("A" & LastRow+1 & ":A1000000").entirerow.delete` this may delete crap rows, not sure though but worth a try.

Comment: Wow. MS chooses to save a bunch of empty lines to data files by default? Just, wow.

Answer (score 3):

`.SaveAs` will save the worksheet, not the selection (I don't see any [options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) to save the selection instead of the whole worksheet). There are blank rows at the end of your data, so they're getting saved into the .CSV.

Try this to delete the blank rows at the end:

```
' DeleteHeadings
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.DeleteShift:=xlUp

'Find thelast Row with data in a Column
Dim LastRow As Long
'Dim FirstRow As Integer       'No longer needed - at least for this snippet

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Rows(LastRow + 1 & ":" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Delete

'SelectRows to Save
'you can comment these 2 lines out vvvv  They're not buying you anything
FirstRow= 1
Range(Cells(FirstRow,"A"), Cells(LastRow, "BH")).Select

' SaveActive Workbook As CSV
Application.DisplayAlerts= False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAsFilename:="Z:\RDS\Towers_Watson_Trans_File1", _
      FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts= True
```

Comment: I think you will want to `Offset(1)` away from the last row or `Rows(LastRow+1 & ...)`.  Otherwise you run the risk of deleting the last row of data also.

Comment: That too.  I always prefer `Offset` on the range to make it obvious which cell I was trying to get to.  Either works.  Good solution either way.